# get previous and next url based on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page that displays all projects ordered by dates. When you click on a project you are brought to a page `project-single.php?id=123` where I have a previous and next button. All of the projects have an id (which is in no sequential order aka not auto_incremented), and a date of creation timestamp (in the form of 2012-07-20 00:36:20) in the `projects` table in the database. I am trying to think of an efficient way to get the id of the project both before and after the `id=123` in terms of date for the prev next buttons. But I cannot think of an easier way than creating an array with the `id` and `date_created` and comparing dates; which as you can imagine would get quite taxing on the server as this is a page accessed often. Does anyone have a cleaner solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp in normal php form"? Which function is producing the timestamps?

Comment: updated question for clarity

Comment: You already have a collection of project details for the main projects page, Can you just make that slightly more "global" in nature and reference that collection to get prev/next, and then get the details for the new project the same way you got them for project123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider changing your timestamp to a [Unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead of a string. Unix timestamps are simple integers, which are easy and efficient for a database to compare.

With a comparison operator, an index on the timestamp, and a LIMIT 1, you should have a very fast SQL statement. Here's some example code:

```
-- For getting the next project.
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE date_created > :current_project_date ORDER BY date_created ASC LIMIT 1;
-- For getting the previous project.
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE date_created < :current_project_date ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not familiar with MySQL, so these results may need some tweaking, but that's the gist.

Comment: could you give me an idea what a comparison operator in this case would look like?

Comment: got it, took .0004 seconds for each query. so simple too.

Comment: Didn't see your comment until after I'd added the example already. If you've got working code, would you mind editing my example code for posterity?

Comment: its actually the same thing, the only difference being the variable of the current timestamp of `123` is being pulled from the previous query. your example is more generally applicable ;)

Comment: i actually noticed i dont have the ASC or DESC but am getting the proper results. i think it shouldn't matter?

Comment: The ASC is technically unnecessary, but it does surprise me that omitting the DESC also gives you the correct results.